# Display values as % of parent node in Ag-grid

Tags: ag-grid, streamlit

As shown in the screenshot, I want to show the values in the leaf node as % of the value in the parent node.

For example, SUN PHARMA : NOV-FEB '23 is shown as 1.484 in EAST, 1.39 in SOUTH and so on… I want to show the values as: 1.484 / 5.057 = 29.3% in EAST, 1.39 / 5.057 = 27.4% in SOUTH. How can I achieve this using aggrid?

[image]